# Why does my program output end with "will be 181" instead of "will be 19"?

Tags: c#, string-concatenation

Ask the user to enter their name and current age.
Write code to print a personalised greeting and tell them how old they will be on their next birthday.

e.g.
If the user enters "Kelly" and "43",
your program should output:

"Hello Kelly, on your next birthday you will be 44."

This is my code, it keeps putting 1 at the end of the number instead of doing addition e.g. "Hello earl, on your next birthday you will be 181" instead of "Hello earl, on your next birthday you will be 19."

```
string name, input;
int age;
Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
name= Console.ReadLine();
Console.WriteLine("What is your age?");
input = Console.ReadLine();
age = Convert.ToInt32(input);
Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name + ", on your next birthday you will be  " + age + 1);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You're missing parentheses to do the integer sum before the string concatenation: `"..." + (x + 1)`. Without them, the operator applies to your arguments left-to-right - as in: `"..." + x + 1` => `"...x" + 1` => `"...x1"`.

Answer (score 2):

Look at this snippet of code:

```cs
"Hello " + name + ", on your next birthday you will be  "+age +1
```

Notice that you have four `+` operators there. What are the first three doing? They are performing string concatenation. You seem to be under the impression that the last one will be done first for some reason. It won't. It will be done last, after the value of `age` has already been concatenated into a string, so it will perform string concatenation as well, which is exactly what you're seeing.

If you expect that numeric addition to be done first, before the string concatenation, then you have to indicate that somehow. One way would be to do it separately first, then use the result in the string concatenation, e.g.

```cs
age = age + 1;
```

The other way would to be indicate that that operation should be done first within the complex expression. If you've done the most basic of mathematics at school, you know that that is done using parentheses:

```cs
"Hello " + name + ", on your next birthday you will be " + (age + 1)
```

EDIT:

By the way, I would recommend that you never use more than one concatenation operator in a single expression. If you need more, use `String.Format` or string interpolation instead. In that case, there would be no concatenation operators so your addition would be performed as you expect:

```cs
$"Hello {name}, on your next birthday you will be {age + 1}"
```

I just noticed that another answer recommends string interpolation but there's at least one flaw in that as it is currently and it doesn't really explain the original problem.

Comment: thanks, you've answered my dilemma too :))

Comment: Thank you so much, I feel so dumb for not knowing this earlier. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @Cutty, this is one of those "not seeing the wood for the trees" situations. You need to take a step back and look at what's actually there but that's easier said than done and we often just see what we expect to see.

Answer (score 0):

***As pointed out in the comments, snippet bellows WILL NOT do the trick!***

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}, on your next birthday you will be {age++}");
```

Don't use `++` if you plan to use `age` variable later on, but if you don't then this will do the trick for you:

```
Console.WriteLine($"Hello {name}, on your next birthday you will be {++age}");
```

Comment: Sorry that I am too lazy to try out this one by myself. Can you check what happens if you just put (age+1) at the end of your string?

Comment: Please note that this will change `age` and this something you may not want.

Comment: ... okay it's a bedtime for me! Of course, it will, I was not thinking about that at all :(

Comment: Will that work? You have used the post-increment operator, which means the current value of `age` is used and then the variable is incremented. I think you'd have to use the pre-increment operator, i.e. `++age`, so that the increment is done first and the final value of the variable used.

Comment: `++age` is better because it will display the correct value, but it's still bad because you would still increment `age`. If the OP decides to use `age` later in the code, it will have an inaccurate value. CC: @jmcilhinney

Comment: Okay, I am so embarrassed at this point that I want to berry this answer underground hahahah. All your comments are absolutely on point. :)

Answer (score 0):

The below code will fix the error

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string name, input;
            int age;
            Console.WriteLine("What is your name?");
            name= Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("What is your age?");
            input = Console.ReadLine();
            age = Convert.ToInt32(input);

            // Change in below line
            Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name + ", on your next birthday you will be  " + (age +1));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

The change is in this line of code

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello " + name + ", on your next birthday you will be  "+(age +1));
```

The reason it keeps putting 1 at the end, is because it is doing a string concatenation on the above line of code.

`Console.WriteLine()` is simply treating all the concatenations as strings. So, `age` is being passed in as a string, and `1` is also treated as a string. So, the program concatenates `18` + `1` giving `181`

By putting this evaluation in paranteses, we instruct the proram to first evaluate what is in the brackets (i.e. 18+1 = 19), thereby returning the desired output